# RESTful API and bulk operations

Tags: rest, http, api-design, bulk, optimistic-concurrency

I have a middle tier which performs CRUD operations on a shared database.  When I converted the product to .NET Core I thought I'd also look at using REST for the API as CRUD is supposed to be what it does well.  It seems like REST is a great solution for single record operations, but what happens when I want to delete, say, 1,000 records?

Every professional multi-user application is going to have some concept of Optimistic Concurrency checking: you can't have one user wipe out the work of another user without some feedback.  As I understand it, REST handles this with the HTTP ETag header record.  If the ETag send by the client doesn't match the server's tag, then you issue a **412 Precondition Failed**.  So far, so good.  But what do I use when I want to delete 1,000 records?  The back-and-forth time for 1,000 individual calls is considerable, so how would REST handle a batch operation that involved **Optimistic Concurrency**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RESTs focus is on resources and the decoupling of clients from servers, it is though not a simple CRUD architecture or protocol. While CRUD and REST seem to be very similar, managing resources through REST principles [can often also have sideeffects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/difference-between-rest-and-crud). Therefore, describing REST as simple CRUD thing is an oversimplification.

In regards to batch-processing of REST resources, the underlying protocol (most often HTTP) does define the capabilities that can be used. HTTP defines a couple of operations that can be used to modify multiple resources.

`POST` is the all-purpose, swiss-army knife of the protocol and can be used to literally manage resources to your likings. As the semantics are defined by the developer you can use it to create, update or delete multiple resources at once.

`PUT` has the semantics of replacing the state of a resource obtainable at a given URI with the payload body of the request. If you send a `PUT` request to a "list"-resource and the payload defines a list of entries, you can achieve a batch operation as well.

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT methods is
> highlighted by the different intent for the enclosed representation.
> The target resource in a POST request is intended to handle the
> enclosed representation according to the resource's own semantics,
> whereas the enclosed representation in a PUT request is defined as
> replacing the state of the target resource.

...

> A PUT request applied to the target resource can have side effects on
> other resources.  For example, an article might have a URI for
> identifying "the current version" (a resource) that is separate from
> the URIs identifying each particular version (different resources that at one point shared the same state as the current version
> resource).  A successful PUT request on "the current version" URI
> might therefore create a new version resource in addition to changing
> the state of the target resource, and might also cause links to be
> added between the related resources.
> ([Source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4))

`PATCH` ([RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)) is not yet included in the HTTP protocol, though supported by plenty frameworks. It is primarily used to alter multiple resources at once or to perform partial updates on resources, which `PUT` is also able to achieve if the updated part is a sub-resource of some other resource; in that case it has the effect of a partial update on the outer resource.

It is important to know that a `PATCH` request contains the necessary steps a server has to fulfill to transform a resource to its intended state. A client therefore has to grab the current state and calculate the necessary steps needed for the transformation beforehand. A very informative blog post on this topic is [Don't patch like an idiot](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/). Here [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) ([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)) is a JSON based media type that visualizes the PATCH concept clearly. A patch request has to be applied either fully (each operation defined in the patch request) or applied not at all. It therefore requires a transaction scoped handling and a roll back in case any of the operations failed.

Conditional requests like `ETag` and `IfModifiedSince` headers are defined in [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) and can be used in HTTP requests to perform the modifications only if the request is applied on the most recent version of resource and therefore correlates to an optimistic locking in (distributed) databases.

> So far, so good. But what do I use when I want to delete 1,000 records?

This depends on what framework you'll use. If it supports `PATCH` I clearly vote for `PATCH`. In case it does not, you are probably safer to use `POST` than `PUT` as of the very restrictive semantics `PUT` has, as the semantics are clearly defined by you then. In case of a batch-delete, `PUT` can also be used by targeting the collection resource with an empty body which has the result of removing any items in the collection and therefore clearing the whole collection. If some of the items should remain in the collection though, `PATCH` or `POST` are probably more easy to use.

Comment: Nitpick: “`PATCH` (RFC 5789) is not yet included in the HTTP protocol” — HTTP is not a closed protocol; there will never be a single document defining all HTTP methods. PATCH is as much of standard HTTP as PUT is.

Comment: I'm afraid you lost me with the 'swiss army knife' approach to POST.  Yes, I understand POST can be used for just about everything, but I already have an API that works.  When I cracked the book on REST I was hoping to find some sort of standardization.  It seems to me that you're just suggesting we roll our own interface using the HTTP verbs, which is not news to me.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury Given the limited set of operations (and semantics) HTTP offers, you either have to chose one of the available ones or come up with a new one (i.e. BATCHDELETE) in an own RFC. If your framework supports `PATCH` use it to your advantage, if not design a way where you can use `PUT` efficiently by adhering to its semantics. If none of these operations are suitable, you probably will have to use `POST` as no other operation will serve your needs. Also note: By returning appropriate error messages on malformed requests you can hint the client on how the payload has to look like.

Comment: @RomanVottner - Yeah, I got all that and I agree it's perfectly solid design for HTTP.  What I don't get is how is this RESTful?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury Well, true RESTful clients start either without any knowledge on the domain or with a limited set. By feeding them with an entry point they'll progress through their task autonomously. They issue i.e. `OPTIONS`, `HEAD` and `GET` requests to the server to learn more about the resources and what kind of operations they can perform on these. They will negotiate with the server about a document format both understand and which the client is able to extract further knowledge or actions from. Due to HATEOAS responses will contain links with relational names that a client can use to

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury sense the meaning and intention of the url. Media types like json+hal and similar stuff are helpful on this regard. An autonomous client will either be given templated URIs which he can replace placeholder properties with properties already in his context or use a trial and error approach to learn based on received errors and contained hints on how to update the request in order to succeed. As this is still pretty much science in progress not many true autonoumous RESTful clients are available yet and plenty of developers misuse the term REST for WebAPI.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury I guess your concern in regards to REST lies in the fact that when you have to issue a PATCH or POST request to the server, that the client has to have some knowledge of the server's capabilities. But the client is just updating the resource it knows to something it whishes it would look like. As the client knows what steps he needed to transform the origin representation to the desired one, he can simply send the instructions to the server. Of course both need to agree on a certain media-type they understand, hence they have to negotiate about it and adapt the request.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want optimistic concurrency for each record individually. That is, each record is to be deleted only if its state matches the client’s expectation. (If you only want to assert the entire collection’s state, then `If-Match` and 412 are sufficient.)

Roman Vottner’s answer does an excellent job of explaining the HTTP methods involved, but I’ll try to fill in some details.

### Caveat emptor

When we talk about “how would REST handle” this or that, you understand that technically you can use HTTP as a transport for any operation in any way that suits you.

So when you’re asking about REST, I’m assuming you’re interested in a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) — an approach that could theoretically be used by a range of various clients and servers.

But the key word there is “theoretically”. For example, once you define your own media type (your own JSON structure), a lot of the uniformity goes down the drain, because a client would have to be coded against your specific API anyway, at which point you can ask it to jump through any hoops you want.

But if you’re still interested in salvaging as much of the uniformity as possible, then read on.

### All or nothing

If you want an all-or-nothing operation, which fails entirely if any of the individual preconditions fails, then, as Roman suggests, you can use [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) with the [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) format. For this, you need a conceptual representation of your collection as a single JSON object, to which the patch is to be applied.

For example, suppose you have resources like `/my/collection/1`, `/my/collection/4`, and so on. You could represent `/my/collection/` as:

```
{
    "resources": {
        "1": {
            "href": "1",
            "etag": "\"BRkDVtYw\"",
            "name": "Foo Bar",
            "price": 1234.5,
            ...
        },
        "4": {
            "href": "4",
            "etag": "\"RCi8knuN\"",
            "name": "Baz Qux",
            "price": 2345.6,
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Here, `"1"` and `"4"` are URLs relative to `/my/collection/`. You could use domain-specific IDs instead, but proper REST operates in terms of opaque URLs.

The standards don’t require you to actually serve this representation on `GET /my/collection/`, but if you do support such a request, then you should use that representation. Anyway, to this structure you can apply the following JSON patch:

```
PATCH /my/collection/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {"op": "test", "path": "/resources/1/etag", "value": "\"BRkDVtYw\""},
    {"op": "remove", "path": "/resources/1"},
    {"op": "test", "path": "/resources/4/etag", "value": "\"RCi8knuN\""},
    {"op": "remove", "path": "/resources/4"},
    ...
]
```

Here, `path` is not a URL path, it’s a [JSON pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) into the above representation.

If all patch operations succeed, then you respond with a successful status code like [204 (No Content)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) or [200 (OK)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).

If any of the ETag `test` operations fails, you respond with [409 (Conflict)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8). You should not respond with [412 (Precondition Failed)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) in this case, because there is no precondition (like `If-Match`) on the request itself.

If anything else goes wrong, you respond with other appropriate status codes: see [RFC 5789 § 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2) and [RFC 7231 § 6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6).

### Mixed result

If you don’t want “all-or-nothing” semantics, then I’m not aware of any standardized solution. As Roman notes, you cannot use the PATCH method in this case, but you can use POST with a custom media type ([RFC 6838 § 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.4)). It could look like this:

```
POST /my/collection/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x.my-patch+json
Accept: application/x.my-patch-results+json

{
    "delete": [
        {"href": "1", "if-match": "\"BRkDVtYw\""},
        {"href": "4", "if-match": "\"RCi8knuN\""},
        ...
    ]
}
```

You can respond to such a request with 200 (OK), regardless of whether any of the individual deletes succeeded. Another option would be [207 (Multi-Status)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-13), but I don’t see any benefits to it in this case, and it’s not widely used outside of WebDAV, so [Postel’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) would suggest not going there.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x.my-patch-results+json

{
    "delete": [
        {"href": "1", "success": true},
        {"href": "4", "success": false, "error": {...}},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Of course, if the patch was invalid in the first place, you should instead respond with [415 (Unsupported Media Type)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) or [422 (Unprocessable Entity)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) as appropriate.

### Another angle

> The back-and-forth time for 1,000 individual calls is considerable

It is in HTTP/1.1. But if you can use HTTP/2 — which has much better support for concurrent requests, as well as much smaller network overhead per request — then 1000 individual requests might work out just fine for you.

Comment: I already have an RPC interface.  In fact, I already support a bulk 'operation' command like you illustrated where you send the test operations and then the delete operations in one batch.  How is this RESTful?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury REST stands for *representational state transfer*. In my PATCH example, you **don’t** ask the server to carry out any domain-specific operations. Instead, you ask it to apply a patch to a *representation* of the collection’s *state*. The patch is in a common, well-defined format, and submitted with a standard HTTP method. This adds up to a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5): a client could bulk-update **any** resource (with a JSON representation) in the **exact same way**.