# Send Array In Delete Reqest to Express from Angular 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I want to delete several elements at once from MongoDB. For this purpose in the backend I want to use deleteMany. But first I need to assign array to ids, then build a query and then perform a delete

```
app.delete('/tasks', function(req,res){
  ids = [];
  var myquery = { _id: { $in: ids } };
  Model.collection.deleteMany(myquery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
      res.json(result)
    }
  });
});
```

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the ids array of IDs to backend from frontend. I tried with requestParameters, but it failed...Also I tried **RequestOptions**, but it is now depreciated...I guess, I should add all IDs as params? How could I iterate trough ids and add it to params? Or maybe there is other better way to this?

```
 deleteData(ids) {
//ids is array of IDs, which I would like to pass as requestOptions

    return this.http.delete( this.api, requestOptions);
  }
```

Comment: You need to set the `ids` ( presumably already a list ) as a value in the request body. Then your express back end needs to read this data from `req.body`. Presuming you have already set up the bodyParser middleware this should be straightforward. If you have not yet set that up then please say so in your question. May I also ask why you are calling with `Model.collection.deleteMany()` instead of `Model.deleteMany()`. Do you have a real reason, or is this just some code you copied from somewhere else?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525753/restful-api-and-bulk-operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reflection, a `DELETE` verb probably is not appropriate for a "list" of content and this would be better suited to a `POST` or `PUT` or even `PATCH`. For all of the other verbs it's generally accepted that these will have a request body which is suitable for keeping data such as a "list".

Generally there is nothing wrong with `POST` and whilst it's [not "official" that `DELETE` should not send a content body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request), you are probably better off sticking with standards, at least from the perspective of what would be most widely supported should your "front end" end up talking to a different "back end" service structure at some later stage.

Therefore if we `POST` instead, then [your angular method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) would be:

```
deleteData(ids) {
  // presuming this.api points to /tasks at the correct point
  return this.http.post( this.api, { ids });
}
```

On the express side you would want to have the [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) set up if you have not already:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And then in your actual route controller, simply return the array from `req.body` with a specifically named route for the `POST` request:

```
app.post('/tasks/delete', function(req,res) {
  var myquery = { _id: { $in: req.body.ids } };
  Model.deleteMany(myquery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
      res.json(result)
    }
  });
});
```

Noting also that mongoose supports [`deleteMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#deletemany_deleteMany) directly on the model, so there is no need to use the `collection` accessor to the underlying driver `Collection` object. Also using the mongoose method ensures that if your list of `ids` are actually meant to be `ObjectId` values ( as they typically are for `_id` ) then they will "autocast" from the strings as which they were sent from the client. Actually whatever the schema type is for the field in any query, mongoose will take care of this when using it's own methods.

Using `DELETE` really should be reserved for single parameter requests "within the url" such as:

```
app.delete('/tasks/:id', function(req,res) {
  var myquery = { _id: req.params.id };
  Model.deleteOne(myquery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
      res.json(result)
    }
  });
});
```